# Android FragmentActivity from inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs, navigation-drawer

In my Android application I have created a simple Navigation Drawer which calls fragments when an item is clicked. From one of these fragments, I want to call a FragmentActivity (which will make scrollable tabs from within one of my fragments). Is this possible? Can someone please help me. A similar example to what I'm trying to achieve is in Play Music. It has a Navigation Drawer and upon selecting 'My Library' it creates a Fragment with scrollable tabs whilst still having the NavDrawer accessible from that page.

Regards,

Comment: Do you mean that you want to start a new activity ?? or to get an instance of the parent activity??

Comment: I want to start my fragmentactivity inside my fragment.

Comment: I guess the question I'm asking is how can I get swipeviews with tabs and still access my navigation drawer on the same screen?

Comment: note i've also looked into tabhost, but to make a swipeable one it also uses fragmentactivity :(

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import cgg.gov.in.apps.eoffice.source.R;

public class TestTabsinsideFragment extends Fragment
{
    View rootView;

public TestTabsinsideFragment () 
{
    // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   

    getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Apply the layout for the fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.approve_leaves, container, false);


    getActivity().setTitle("New tabbed layout inside Fragment :-) ");


    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // show the given tab
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // hide the given tab
        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // probably ignore this event
        }
    };

    // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 3; i1++) {
        getActivity().getActionBar().addTab(
                getActivity().getActionBar().newTab()
                .setText("Tab " + (i1 + 1))
                .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }


    return rootView;
}
```

Did this answer your question ??

Include this code in your Fragment and call it from **onSelectItem()** of Nav-Drawer